# GO SMS interferes with abortbroadcast()

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have a problem aborting SMS broadcasts while GO SMS is installed, apparently it always has a higher priority than my sms blocker app. See this post( [Suppress / Block BroadcastReceiver in another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600266/suppress-block-broastreceiver-in-another-app) ). I've tried the solution suggested in the post above, setting the highest possible priority integer for my app, and also tried the First-app-installed rule mentioned there. But it doesn't seem to work. Do you guys have any ideas about how I can put my app in a higher priority than GO SMS? And does GO SMS do it just by setting its priority to 2147483647?

Comment: hi, i have the same problem! did you find out the solution?

Comment: @ZuzooVn No, unfortunately I couldn't. The solution I could come up with was to warn the user of the receivers with a high priority which hardly can be considered a solution, but is better than nothing.

Comment: Hi, see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759621/sms-listener-make-some-application-force-close