# Block Go sms to get sms broadcast

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have a sms broad cast listener, defined in manisfest as:

```
<receiver android:name=".CustomSmsListener" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When my phone has Go sms installed. When an sms is received, both the receivers work however I dont want Go sms to work. My app is the first app to be installed in the phone, hence that receiver is called first. Also, I am aborting the broadcast in my listener as:

```
if (isDelete()) {
    abortBroadcast();
}
```

I have checked out [this sof question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600266/suppress-block-broastreceiver-in-another-app), but nothing seems to work.

Also, a bit of confusion about a warning I am getting, which might be causing this ambiguity. On the first line of receiver declaration in manifest, i.e.

```
<receiver android:name=".CustomSmsListener" >
```

i get following warning

`Exported receiver does not require permission`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use           `android:priority="999"` i guess this is the last limit of priority

```
   <receiver android:name=".CustomSmsListener" >
       <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
      </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```