# How to change the default messaging app in Gingerbread

Tags: android, sms, messaging, android-4.4-kitkat, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have an app that can be changed as the default messaging app if users choose so when he sees the request dialog in KitKat but when I test it on Gingerbread, I do not need to set it the default messaging app in order to write, delete or edit an sms.
This is not an issue. The issue is that my onReceive Broadcast saves the sms in the inbox table, as does the stock messaging app. So in my inbox every sms appears twice.

What is the solution in this case? Can I change the default messaging app in lower Android versions than KitKat?

Comment: You can't change the default messaging app in lower ANdroid because this feature doesn't exist (http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html).
But you can set the priority of your broadcast receiver to be the first to receive the message, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600266/suppress-block-broastreceiver-in-another-app

Comment: Your app should be checking the Android version it's running on, and its default status (if applicable), to determine its behavior. Receiver priority is kind of irrelevant in this case.